# Audio is not mixing in MediaStream

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, screen-recording, web-mediarecorder

i'm trying build a screen recorder using mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia (screen and system audio)
and mediaDevices.getUserMedia (mic audio) in this line i'm mixing the streams. mixedStream = new MediaStream([...stream.getTracks(), ...audio.getTracks()]); but the output is only mic audio is captured

if audio is true in getDisplayMedia only system audio is captured.

if audio is true in getUserMedia only mic auido is captured.

if both true only the system audio is captured.

my expectation is to capture both system and mic audio. i search all type of resource all are point to do like this ---> mixedStream = new MediaStream([...stream.getTracks(), ...audio.getTracks()]);

but it is not working as expected.

I am new to this API's can anyone share what is worong with this code im shareing the gibhub link here [text](https://github.com/TylerPottsDev/yt-js-screen-recorder) refer dist folder main.js file.
`

```
let stream = null,
    audio = null,
    mixedStream = null,
    chunks = [], 
    recorder = null
    startButton = null,
    stopButton = null,
    downloadButton = null,
    recordedVideo = null;

async function setupStream () {
    try {
        stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
            
        });

        audio = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: {
                //echoCancellation: true,
                //noiseSuppression: true,
                sampleRate: 44100,
            },
        });

        setupVideoFeedback();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

function setupVideoFeedback() {
    if (stream) {
        const video = document.querySelector('.video-feedback');
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    } else {
        console.warn('No stream available');
    }
}

async function startRecording () {
    await setupStream();

    if (stream && audio) {
        mixedStream = new MediaStream([...stream.getTracks(), ...audio.getTracks()]);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(mixedStream);
        recorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
        recorder.onstop = handleStop;
        recorder.start(1000);
    
        startButton.disabled = true;
        stopButton.disabled = false;
    
        console.log('Recording started');
    } else {
        console.warn('No stream available.');
    }
}

function stopRecording () {
    recorder.stop();

    startButton.disabled = false;
    stopButton.disabled = true;
}

function handleDataAvailable (e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
}

function handleStop (e) {
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
    chunks = [];

    downloadButton.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadButton.download = 'video.mp4';
    downloadButton.disabled = false;

    recordedVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    recordedVideo.load();
    recordedVideo.onloadeddata = function() {
        const rc = document.querySelector(".recorded-video-wrap");
        rc.classList.remove("hidden");
        rc.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });

        recordedVideo.play();
    }`



    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    audio.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());

    console.log('Recording stopped');
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    startButton = document.querySelector('.start-recording');
    stopButton = document.querySelector('.stop-recording');
    downloadButton = document.querySelector('.download-video');
    recordedVideo = document.querySelector('.recorded-video');

    startButton.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
    stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
})`
```

im expecting to record the screen with system audio (tab/all) and mic audio (from system mic / pluged earphone). using javascript.

Happy coding!